# Array multisort not working for an array

Tags: php, sorting, array-multisort

```
$artists = [
  0 => [
    "id" => "3",
    "plan_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Artist-A",
    "views" => "1189189",
    "soundcloud" => "42",
    "facebook" => "59881948",
    "twitter" => "21760757",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "3429017"
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => "10",
    "plan_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Artist-B",
    "views" => "1",
    "soundcloud" => 0,
    "facebook" => 0,
    "twitter" => 0,
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => 0
  ],
  2 => [
    "id" => "2",
    "plan_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Artist-C",
    "views" => "1629",
    "soundcloud" => "20",
    "facebook" => "5025158",
    "twitter" => "582899",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "112127"
  ],
  3 => [
    "id" => "4",
    "plan_id" => "2",
    "name" => "Artist-D",
    "views" => "484353",
    "soundcloud" => "7",
    "facebook" => "104449606",
    "twitter" => "36820201",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "16483226"
  ],
  4 => [
    "id" => "5",
    "plan_id" => "2",
    "name" => "Artist-E",
    "views" => "98765432",
    "soundcloud" => "13",
    "facebook" => "59551072",
    "twitter" => "38995648",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "64997436"
  ]
]

foreach ($remaining_artists as $key => $value) {
   $soundcloud[$key] = $value['soundcloud'];
}

array_multisort($soundcloud, SORT_ASC, $artists);
```

I use array_multisort to sort array. It's working perfectly fine. But there is an error 'array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent' for the above array. I really can't figure out what's the problem here and its solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your array_multisort() parameters were out of order.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Also, syntax problems.

This works

```
<?php

$artists = [
  0 => [
    "id" => "3",
    "plan_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Artist-A",
    "views" => "1189189",
    "soundcloud" => "42",
    "facebook" => "59881948",
    "twitter" => "21760757",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "3429017"
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => "10",
    "plan_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Artist-B",
    "views" => "1",
    "soundcloud" => 0,
    "facebook" => 0,
    "twitter" => 0,
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => 0
  ],
  2 => [
    "id" => "2",
    "plan_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Artist-C",
    "views" => "1629",
    "soundcloud" => "20",
    "facebook" => "5025158",
    "twitter" => "582899",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "112127"
  ],
  3 => [
    "id" => "4",
    "plan_id" => "2",
    "name" => "Artist-D",
    "views" => "484353",
    "soundcloud" => "7",
    "facebook" => "104449606",
    "twitter" => "36820201",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "16483226"
  ],
  4 => [
    "id" => "5",
    "plan_id" => "2",
    "name" => "Artist-E",
    "views" => "98765432",
    "soundcloud" => "13",
    "facebook" => "59551072",
    "twitter" => "38995648",
    "youtube" => 0,
    "instagram" => "64997436"
  ]
];

$soundcloud = [];

foreach ($artists as $key => $value) {
   $soundcloud[$key] = $value['soundcloud'];
}

array_multisort($soundcloud, $artists,  SORT_ASC);

print_r($artists);
```